# How can I shrink this code to a one-liner?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

I am using `CarrierWave` and find myself doing this all the time:

```
fin = File.open(payload_file_name,'rb')
self.payload = fin
fin.close
```

where `payload` is my `CarrierWave` field. I considered doing:

```
self.payload = File.open(payload_file_name,'rb')
```

but I was concerned it would leave the file open and my app server would eventually run out of file pointers. Is there a Rubyism that will let me assign the return value of a simple block to a variable?

Comment: Do you mean `self.payload = fin.read` ?

Comment: CarrierWave apparently does that automatically with the file pointer, because it works like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible using a block with [`open`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/IO.html#method-c-open):

```
File.open(payload_file_name,'rb') do |fin|
  self.payload = fin.read
end
```

You can reduce that further, to a single line, but it won't accomplish anything additional:

```
File.open(payload_file_name,'rb') { |fin| self.payload = fin.read }
```

You could also use [`read`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/IO.html#method-c-read):

```
self.payload = File.read(payload_file_name, :mode => 'rb')
```

But you knew all that after reading the documentation, right?

Comment: There's also `self.payload = File.open(payload_file_name, 'rb', &:read)`.

Comment: I hadn't even thought of exactly which documentation to read. Got it.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`IO::read`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/IO.html#method-c-read):

```
self.payload = File.read(payload_file_name, mode: 'rb')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a block to File.open() and it will close automatically after the block finishes execution. Something like(untested):

```
File.open('payload_file_name', 'rb') do | file |
  # do stuff with file
end
```

Or the one-liner version.

```
File.open('payload_file_name', 'rb') {|file| # do stuff }
```